# Why $\|u\|_{L^{2}}\|v\|_{L^{2}}+\|v'\|_{L^{2}}+\|u'\|_{L^{2}}≤\|v\|_{H^{1}}\|u\|_{H^{1}}$

Tags: inequality, lebesgue-measure, sobolev-spaces, integral-inequality

I see this steps from a book !

$I=]0,1[$ defined on $H^{1}$

$$a(u,v)=\int_{I}u'v'dx+\int_{I}u\cdot\int_{I}v$$

So in solution I find this steps :

\begin{align*}
\|u\|_{L^{2}}\|v\|_{L^{2}}+\|v'\|_{L^{2}}+\|u'\|_{L^{2}}&\le(\|v\|_{L^{2}}+\|v'\|_{L^{2}})(\|u\|_{L^{2}}+\|u'\|_{L^{2}})\\
&≤\|v\|_{H^{1}}\|u\|_{H^{1}}\end{align*}

Also why is

$$|v(0)|≤\|v\|_{L^{\infty}}\le\|v\|_{L^{2}}?$$

I know that:

$$\|u\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)}=\sqrt{\int_{\Omega}(|u|^{2}+|\nabla {u}|^{2})\,dx}$$

Also:

$$\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}=\sqrt{\int_{\Omega}|u|^{2}\,dx}.$$

$$\Omega\subset{\mathbb{R^{n}}$$
But I can't see this inequality!?

Answer (score 1):

$|v(0)| \leq ||v||_{L^{\infty}}$ because $||v||_{L^{\infty}}$ is the maximum value $|v(x)|$ can take.

I think in fact also $||v||_{L^2} \leq ||v||_{L^{\infty}}$ because $||v||_{L^2} = (\int_0^1 v(x)^2 )^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq (\int_0^1 ||v||_{L^{\infty}}^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = ||v||_{L^{\infty}}$

Comment: i think $||v||_{L^2} \geq ||v||_{L^{\infty}}$ ?? Do you mean $L^{\infty}$ is maxi maximum but by definition is inf {...}

Comment: Take $v(x) = x$. $||v||_{L^{\infty}} = 1$ but $||v||_{L^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: $L^{\infty}$ is always maximum as far as I know

Comment: @GeorgeDawhirst Ok sir I understand you , thanks!

Comment: can you explain to me first step ? \begin{align*}
\|u\|_{L^{2}}\|v\|_{L^{2}}+\|v'\|_{L^{2}}+\|u'\|_{L^{2}}&\le(\|v\|_{L^{2}}+\|v'\|_{L^{2}})(\|u\|_{L^{2}}+\|u'\|_{L^{2}})\\
&≤\|v\|_{H^{1}}\|u\|_{H^{1}}\end{align*}

Comment: I think that this is in general false, take $u = x, v = x$, $u' = 1, v' = 1$.

LHS = $\frac{7}{3}$.
RHS = $\frac{4}{3}$.